# Android IabHelper check if purchases

Tags: java, android, google-api, billing

If the purchase has been made I want to open an activity, otherwise I want to open the activity for purchase. I entered the class IabHelper to do this but I do not get any results.

Where am I wrong?

Code snippet:

```
private void Controlla_record_per_acquisto(){
     SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity()).getReadableDatabase();
    String controllo = "SELECT COUNT(_id) FROM table";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(controllo, null);

    while (c.moveToNext()){
        int numero_id = c.getInt(0);            

    if(numero_id >=1){  

        IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener 
        = new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, 
                        Purchase purchase) 
        {
           if (result.isFailure()) {
              // Handle error
              return;
         }      
         else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {

            Intent intent = null;
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Ce.class); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }

       }
    };  

    }else   {       
        Intent intent = null;
        intent = new Intent(getActivity(), InAppBillingActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    c.close();
    db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to get data about you're inventory.

Nice article to read:

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html

How to call method:

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, base64EncodedPublicKey);

mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true);

mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {

if (!result.isSuccess()) {
return;
}

if (mHelper == null) return;
List<String> st = new ArrayList<String>();
st.add(ITEM_SKU);
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true,st,mGotInventoryListener);
}
});
```

How to query inventory for the items.

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {

if (mHelper == null) return;

if (result.isFailure()) {
return;
}

if(inventory.hasPurchase(ITEM_SKU)) {
Intent intent = null;
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Ce.class); 
startActivity(intent);
}
}
};
```

Comment: when I invoke the method `Controlla_record_per_acquisto()` nothing happens. maybe I need to do something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not adjust the second part of the code you've written. Go in the method or in the onCreate ()? Thanks for your help

Comment: first code block goes to onCreate() method. Second code sniper add like simple class method.

Comment: I entered the first part of the code in the OnCreate (), but mGotInventoryListener, `mGotInventoryListener can not be resolved to a variable`

Comment: import com.alllarm.utils.store.IabHelper;
import com.alllarm.utils.store.IabResult;
import com.alllarm.utils.store.Inventory;
import com.alllarm.utils.store.Purchase; do you add imports?

Comment: Also look at http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html

Comment: I added the import. I'm using Fragment, maybe it's something else?